# Angular - Wait until I receive data before loading template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that renders several components dynamically, with this template:

```
<div [saJquiAccordion]="{active: group.value['collapsed']}" *ngFor="let group of filterGroupsTemplate | keysCheckDisplay;">
    <div>
        <h4>{{group.key | i18n}}</h4>
        <form id="ibo-{{group.key}}" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" style="overflow: initial">
            <fieldset *ngFor="let field of group.value | keys">
                <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="fieldSets[field.value.template];
                                    ngModuleFactory: smartadminFormsModule;"></ng-container>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The thing is that the data needed to fill those components I'm getting it from an API call:

```
      this.getFiltersSubscription = this.getFilters().subscribe(
            (filters) => {
                this.filters = filters;
                log.info('API CALL. getting filters');

                // Sending data to fieldform components
                this.iboService.updateIBOsRankList(filters['iboRank'].data);
                this.iboService.updateIBOsNewsletterOptions(filters['iboNewsletter'].data);
                this.iboService.updateIBOsTotalOrders(filters['iboTotalOrders'].data);
            }
        );
```

So, once I have my data, I'm triggering a service Observable which my components are subscribed to, and they will then process the gathered data.

**PROBLEM**

If the API call is made before all components load, I'll be triggering these service methods passing data but nobody will be subscribed to those Observables.

An approach would be to:

Load data first, and only when I have the data loaded, I'll render the template and, therefore, render all these components dynamically and only then I'll be triggering these service methods (Observables).

I don't want to make an API call for each component, because it can be like 60 components, I'll rather loose abstraction fo code but I prefer to do something like this:

```
// Listens to field's init and creates the fieldset triggering a service call that will be listened by the field component
        this.iboService.initIBOsFilters$.subscribe(
            (fieldName) => {
                if (fieldName === 'IBOsRankSelectorFieldComponent') {
                    log.data('inside initIBOsFilters$ subscription, calling updateIBOsFilters()', fieldName);
                    this.iboService.updateIBOsRankList(this.filters['iboRank'].data); // HERE I'M PASSING DATA TO THE COMPONENT RENDERED DYNAMICALY. BUT IF this.filters IS UNDEFINED, IT BREAKS
                }
            }
        );
```

In order to do this, I need to ensure that `this.filters` is defined and thus, I come to conclusion:

How can I wait until API call ends and `this.filters` is defined before rendering my template html?

Sorry if my question is a bit long, if you need any more details just let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Please try async pipe https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: @Gary I'm having a look. But, could you post an example? I used several times `async` pipe in `ngFor`, for example. But I never used async pipe with an observable that is not rendered. I'm not rendering `filters` nor *printing* it, I just need to wait until it's defined in order to load the entire template.

Comment: Can't you just add an `*ngIf = filters` to block the template rendering until `filters` is filled?

Comment: considering the architecture perspective, `filters` is a sort of dependency for your component, so, you must provide it before the component activation, may `filters` could be a service? or a thing you need to **resolve** before constructor initialisation?

Comment: @Saravana I'm trying `*ngIf="filters | async"`, I have tried `*ngIf="filters"` previously, but no success. I'll let you know if with async pipe works.

Comment: @Hitmands Hey! `filters` is the result of an API call. Is an object with some data that I need. As I don't want to make multiple calls to the Backend. I'm making one main call, and all the components feed from it. So, this data is not on every single component, but in this *parent* component that renders the others in a dynamic way. So, not bein a Service but a property of the Component Class, I don't think I can add it to providers. But thanks! :D

Comment: You should, if your `data` is a top level layer for your application, then you should expose it through some `service` and let each dependant component use it as a dependency. Otherwise, you should load that data in a route resolve. I strongly thing that your problem resides on using that data as a single property for a component.

Comment: Try this simple example. Should help. http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-async-pipe-example

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-async-data-binding-with-ng-if-and-ng-else

Comment: @Gary Hey! At the end async pipe was the solution. but not an obvious one. I had to find the correc tcombination of elements to make it work. Had to create a custom Promise, among other things. Have a loog at my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Great. Lovely to put a plunker for other people's ease. ;-)

Comment: i think you should be using subjects

Comment: @Saravana worked for me.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

After studying the different approaches that people gave me, I found the solution on the `async` pipe. But, it took me a while to understand how to implement it.

**Solution:**

```
// Declaring the Promise, yes! Promise!
filtersLoaded: Promise<boolean>;

// Later in the Component, where I gather the data, I set the resolve() of the Promise
this.getFiltersSubscription = this.getFilters().subscribe(
    (filters) => {
        this.filters = filters;
        log.info('API CALL. getting filters');

        this.filtersLoaded = Promise.resolve(true); // Setting the Promise as resolved after I have the needed data
    }
);

// In this listener triggered by the dynamic components when instanced,
// I pass the data, knowing that is defined because of the template change

// Listens to field's init and creates the fieldset triggering a service call
// that will be listened by the field component
this.iboService.initIBOsFilters$.subscribe(
    (fieldName) => {
        if (fieldName === 'IBOsRankSelectorFieldComponent') {
            log.data('inside initIBOsFilters$ subscription, calling updateIBOsFilters()', fieldName);
            this.iboService.updateIBOsRankList(this.filters['iboRank'].data);
        }
    }
);
```

In the template, I use the `async` pipe that needs an `Observable` or a `Promise`

```
<div *ngIf="filtersLoaded | async">
    <div [saJquiAccordion]="{active: group.value['collapsed']}" *ngFor="let group of filterGroupsTemplate | keysCheckDisplay;">
        <div>
            <h4>{{group.key | i18n}}</h4>
            <form id="ibo-{{group.key}}" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" style="overflow: initial">
                <fieldset *ngFor="let field of group.value | keys">
                    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="fieldSets[field.value.template];
                                    ngModuleFactory: smartadminFormsModule;"></ng-container>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**

- `async` pipe need an `Observable` or a `Promise` from what I understood, that's why the only way to make it work was by creating a `Promise`
- I didn't use the `resolver` approach because it's used when you arrive to the component through Angular's routing. This component is part of a larger component and it's not instanced through routing like any other normal component. *(Tried that approach though, worked a bit with it, didn't do the job)*

Comment: Can you share resolver approach too? that would be great to compare with `promise`. Your ans is working like charm. Thank you

Comment: what about to just use a variable rather than use promises? like isloaded=false, and change to true when data is loaded.

Comment: @CristianSepulveda The original issue was that. If we don't use a Promise, we can't use `async` pipe. And without `async` pipe the template will not update when the actual data is loaded.

Comment: Why do you want to go down this path when you can *ngIf on this.filters instead?

Answer (score 19):

You could use a `resolver` to ensure those data are loaded (or your filters have been initialized) before the route is activated.

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: In all examples and documentation I found that this works when navigating passing an id as parameter. Does it work in a *standard* component? If so, could you provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, using resolvers with an ID is the typical example, but it's up to you what you do with it. Just define a resolver and return from the implemented resolve function after your ``initIBOsFilters$`` has initialized the filters.

Comment: I'm looking into it. As I didn't find a suitable solution with `async` pipe I'm looking into `resolver` examples and documentation. You are saying that I can wait until `initIBOsFilters$` finishes and then render my Component? The issue is that each filter component *(it's a dynamic form with a lot of filters)* will trigger `initIBOsFilters$`, so I don't actually know when All the components loaded dynamically finish to load. Any tips? Examples?

Comment: Your components don't need to trigger ``initIBOsFilters$`` anymore as the resolvers will provide the result of the subscription to those components whose routes are configured with the respective resolver. All of your child components (either dynamically or statically created) will receive non-undefined _filters_ as long as one of the parent components are configured with the resolver. You can access those data in your constructor from the ``ActivatedRoute`` before anything gets rendered. See the first link in my post.

Comment: Hey friend! I tried your approach, but it works when you *arrive* to the component through Angular's routing. In my case, the component is part of a larger and bigger component, so this solution didn't work for me. Obviously, I'll give you my +1 for the effort and the idea, even though no examples were posted. Thanks man, I'll keep your apporach in mind for when it's suitable!

Comment: Hey SrAxi. thank you. As a hint, you could also add the resolver to the (larger and bigger) parent component and access the resolved data in all of its child components. If you configure the resolver to your root component, you can make sure the filters are initialized before any template is rendered.

Comment: hahaha! That's exactly what I did! :D But, how my App is structured, is not the best decission context wise. But, nonetheless, I'll go with this approach for other components that are directly invoked with routing! :P

Answer (score 11):

```
<p class="p-large">{{homeData?.meta[0].site_desc}}</p>
```

Just Used a "?" after the variable that has been getting loaded with data from the server.

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from '../services/home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public homeData: any;
  constructor(private homeService: HomeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.homeService.getHomeData().subscribe( data => {
      this.homeData = data[0];
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this one helped me. Thanks mate

Comment: This is by far the quickest easiest solution.

Comment: That will just not display anything at all if homeData = false. Which is exactly the problem OP is trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to `async` would be creating variable `isLoading = true`. While it´s true show spinner provided by angular instead of content using ***ngIf**. When your subscription triggers, assign `isLoading = false`.
This way you will not receive any errors about missing data since content that is using it technically won´t exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This is not the correct nor the best way but:
**

Easiest solution would be to wrap it in ngIf, i don't think this is a good practice but it resolve the problem.

In this case error is: Title of undifined

```
<div *ngIf="form">
  {{form.Title}}
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem, it just means that no data will be displayed. Part of the page will be missing.

Comment: But you can't display data that you don't yet have!

Comment: @RichardBarraclough the div won't be rendered if form is false

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late to the party, but what works for me is adding a loading boolean to my state in my reducer.

reducer.ts:

```
export interface State {
 things: Stuff;
 loaded: boolean;
}
```

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
    things: reducer,
    loaded: loadedReducer,
};
```

then make sure to export the loaded function so it toggles to true when the state comes back

```
export function loadedReducer(state: boolean = false, action: ThingActions): boolean {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ThingActionTypes.GetThings:
            return true;
    }
    return state;
}
```

then in your ts subscribe to the loaded.

parent.component.ts:

```
this.loaded$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromReducer.loaded));
```

and use this like an async pipe in your template.

parent.component.html:

```
        <ng-container *ngIf="(loaded$ | async); else loading">
            <child-component></child-component>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #loading></ng-template>
```