# how so synchronize GET API call in Angular Component?

Tags: rest

I just started with Angular and I have an issue with its components and an API call. I have the following content in these files

user.component.html:

```
<div>
 <p>
  {{user.name}}
 </p>
</div>
```

user.component.ts:

```
getUser() {
 this.user = this.postService.getPosts();
 console.log('TWO');
 console.log(this.user);
 return false;
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
getPosts(){ 
 this.http.get('https://XXXXX/yyy').subscribe(data => {
       this.str = data[0];
       console.log('ONE');         
    });
 return this.str;
}
```

The Get response is done correctly and I am able to display the data in the html file ONLY if user is loaded, but the first time that I try to do the request to the API the component.ts finishes its execution before the service, and user is not populated correctly, making the html render empty, so with  above code I get this printed in console:

- TWO
- undefined
- ONE

I think if it would be synchronized, it would print:

- ONE
- John
- Two

I found this post but I wasn't able to understand it: [Angular - Wait until I receive data before loading template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900769/angular-wait-until-i-receive-data-before-loading-template)

Can someone please try to help me with this?

Comment: You want to look into using a Promise and returning observables (IIRC)

Comment: yes, with an observable.